# Realm Result returning null

Tags: java, android, database, realm

The Java class RecipeDetailed

```
public class RecipeDetailed extends RealmObject {

@PrimaryKey
private int id;

private String servings;

private String title;

private String image;

private String readyInMinutes;

private boolean vegetarian;

private boolean vegan;

private boolean glutenFree;

private boolean dairyFree;

private RealmList<AnalyzedInstructions> analyzedInstructions;

@Ignore
private ArrayList<Ingredient> extendedIngredients;

public RecipeDetailed() {
}

public RecipeDetailed(int id, String servings, String title, String image, String readyInMinutes, boolean vegetarian, boolean vegan, boolean glutenFree, boolean dairyFree, RealmList<AnalyzedInstructions> analyzedInstructions, ArrayList<Ingredient> extendedIngredients) {
    this.id = id;
    this.servings = servings;
    this.title = title;
    this.image = image;
    this.readyInMinutes = readyInMinutes;
    this.vegetarian = vegetarian;
    this.vegan = vegan;
    this.glutenFree = glutenFree;
    this.dairyFree = dairyFree;
    this.analyzedInstructions = analyzedInstructions;
    this.extendedIngredients = extendedIngredients;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getServings() {
    return servings;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public String getReadyInMinutes() {
    return readyInMinutes;
}

public RealmList<AnalyzedInstructions> getAnalyzedInstructions() {
    return analyzedInstructions;
}

public boolean isVegetarian() {
    return vegetarian;
}

public boolean isVegan() {
    return vegan;
}

public boolean isGlutenFree() {
    return glutenFree;
}

public boolean isDairyFree() {
    return dairyFree;
}

public ArrayList<Ingredient> getExtendedIngredients() {
    return extendedIngredients;
}}
```

The Java Class Favourites

```
public class Favourites extends RealmObject {

private RecipeDetailed recipes;

@PrimaryKey
private int id;

public Favourites() {
}

public Favourites(RecipeDetailed recipes, int id) {
    this.recipes = recipes;
    this.id = id;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public RecipeDetailed getRecipes() {
    return recipes;
}

public void setRecipes(RecipeDetailed recipes) {
    this.recipes = recipes;
}}
```

The way i save the data is through this

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                    Favourites favourites = realm.createObject(Favourites.class,recipeDetailed.getId());
                    favourites.setRecipes(recipeDetailed);
                }
            });
```

Fetching data using

```
favourites = realm.where(Favourites.class).findAll();
```

Log.i("data",element.get(0).getId()+""+element.get(0).getRecipes().getTitle());

The problem is the first part returns the correct data ie,getid returns the correct id but getrecipes returns a null object.Any idea where i went wrong?

Comment: Is `recipeDetailed` a managed RealmProxy?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce i have never come across that term before so i am not sure,could you tell me what exactly it is and how i could check if it is one or not

Comment: in Realm 2.x, you can check `realmObject.isManaged()`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce i tried that and its false

Comment: in that case that's why :P you can either call `insertOrUpdate(favourites)` or just `favourites.setRecipes(realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(recipeDetailed));` or query the `recipeDetailed` you'd like to set

Comment: @JudeFernandes Didn't it throw an `IllegalArgumentException` when you call `favourites.setRecipes(recipeDetailed);` where the `recipeDetailed` is an unmanaged RealmObject?

Comment: @beeender nope it didnt but what i did not is  Favourites favourites = realm.createObject(Favourites.class, recipeDetailed.getId());
                        favourites.setRecipes(realm.copyToRealm(recipeDetailed));
                        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(favourites); but when i try fetching the data , i successfully get the id but getrecipe returns a null object

Comment: That sounds incorrect if you were using `favourites.setRecipes(realm.copyToRealm(recipeDetailed)); ` Did you write and fetch data in two different thread? if that is the case, your data in the fetching thread is probably behind the updated version. Use listener to get data after it updated.